# Persisting Firebase Realtime Database creates null value in snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So my application was working fine; I persisted the database locally using:

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

I didn't change anything but then all of a sudden it started returning a null snapshot. When I comment out that line, everything is working fine again and the label in the interface is displayed correctly, and this value is synced correctly across multiple devices. Here is a code snippet from my viewDidLoad:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var returnedName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scannedURLTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var reentries: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var visitors: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticketType: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var entryOrReentrySwitch: UISwitch!


    var qrDecodedURL : String!
    var ticketNumber : String!
    var eventID : String!
    var numberOfAttendees: String!
    var urlDictionary = [String : Any]()
    var attendeeRef: DatabaseReference!
    var ticketRef : DatabaseReference!
    var entries : DatabaseReference!
    var entriesRef : DatabaseReference!
    var reentriesRef : DatabaseReference!
    var entriesInt : Int!
    var reentriesInt : Int!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true

        attendeeRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "attendees")
        ticketRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "tickets")

        entriesRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "entries")

        reentriesRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "reentries")

        self.scannedURLTextField .becomeFirstResponder()
        scannedURLTextField.inputView=UIView()//create dummy view to supress keyboard

        //        Incresase size of switch
        entryOrReentrySwitch.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5);

        //monitor for changes in entries
        entriesRef.child("entries").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot);
            self.visitors.text = "Visitors: \(snapshot.value as! String)"
            let tempValue = snapshot.value as! String
            self.entriesInt = Int(tempValue)
        })


        //Monitor for changes in reentries
        reentriesRef.child("reentries").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            //            print(snapshot);
            self.reentries.text = "Reentries: \(snapshot.value as! String)"
        })

        statusImage.image = UIImage.init(named: "scanQR.png")
    }
```

The error generated is:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1fb2f3270) to 'NSString' (0x1fb2fcab8).
2019-10-12 18:05:54.061687-0700 VIM Tickets[621:97014] Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1fb2f3270) to 'NSString' (0x1fb2fcab8).
```

It fails on the `self.visitors.text = "Visitors: \(snapshot.value as! String)"` in the monitor for changes in entries section. Again, everything is working fine and there is data in the snapshot when I comment out the database persistence line. I even moved it to the AppDelegate, but it has the same result.

I am at a bit of a loss as to why this is happening when persistence was working before. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I also upgraded to the latest version of the Firebase SDK (note: you'll probably have to reinstall Cocoapds (sudo gem install cocoapods) if you have recently upgraded to macOS Catalina before you do a pod update), but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

When you have disk persistence enabled, the Firebase client immediately fires with the current value that it knows for the node. It sounds like in your case it thinks that value is `null`, so it fires with that. If you have a connection to the server, it will moments later fire with the correct value that it got from the server.

The normal approach to deal with this situation is to first [check whether the snapshot exists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#exists), before processing its contents.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not certain how to approach this as Firebase demands that the  Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true needs to be the first statement before any other DB operations. If you put it after you retrieve a snapshot or set up a reference it gives the error: "Calls to setPersistenceEnabled must be made before any other usage of FIRDatabase instance." Can you be a little more explicit in your explanation please?

Comment: In the completion handler of your `.observe(.value,`, first check `if snapshot.exists()`, before processing its contents.